# How to extract a text using regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

My Text

```
1618148163#@#JASSER-PC#-#1125015374#@#anas kayyat#-#1543243035#@#anas kayyat#-#
```

Result Should Be:

```
JASSER-PC
anas kayyat
anas kayyat
```

I am using :

```
(?<=#@#)(.+)(?=#-#)
```

But it gives me that :

```
JASSER-PC#-#1125015374#@#anas kayyat#-#1543243035#@#anas kayyat
```

Comment: Look behind assertions `(?< ... )` and positive look-ahead `(?= ... )` aren't supported in Javascript regular expressions.

Comment: @Linus:  half right - look-ahead is supported, look-behind isn't.

Comment: @Linus Kleen: Look-ahead assertions are supported.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JavaScript’s regular expressions don’t support look-behind assertions (i.e. `(?<=…)` and `(?<!…)`), so you can’t use that regular expression. But you can use this:

```
#@#(.+)(?=#-#)
```

Then just take the matched string of the first group. Additionally, to only match as little as possible, make the `+` quantifier non-greedy by using `+?`.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript does not support lookbehinds. Make the quantifier non greedy, and use:

```
var regex = /#@#(.+?)#-#/g;
var strings = [];
var result;
while ((result = regex.exec(input)) != null) {
  strings.push(result[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The group `(.+)` will match as much as it can (it's "greedy"). To make it find a minimal match you can use `(.+?)`.

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you a non-regex answer, since using regular expressions isn't always appropriate, be it speed or readibility of the regex itself:

```
function getText(text) {
    var arr = text.split("#@#"); // arr now contains [1618148163,JASSER-PC#-#1125015374,anas kayyat#-#1543243035,anas kayyat#-#]
    var newarr = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        var index = arr[i].indexOf("#-#");

        if(index != -1) {  // if an array element doesn't contain "#-#", we ignore it
            newarr.push(arr[i].substring(0, index));    
        }
    }

    return newarr;
}
```

Now, using

```
getText("1618148163#@#JASSER-PC#-#1125015374#@#anas kayyat#-#1543243035#@#anas kayyat#-#");
```

returns what you wanted.